# Entity Framework : Table per Concrete Type and unique IDs across tables

Tags: sql, inheritance, entity-framework-4

I have a few tables that share only a few navigation properties and an ID.
I think Table per Concrete type inheritance would be interesting here.. (?)
It looks something like this :

Contact (Base, Abstract, not mapped)
- ContactID
- navigation properties to other tables (email, phone, ..)

Person : Contact (mapped to table Person with various properties + ContactID)
- various properties

Company : Contact (mapped to table Company with various properties + ContactID)
- various properties

Now for this to work, the primary key (contactID) should be unique across all tables.
2 options then: 
- GUIDs (not a fan)
- an additional DB table generating identities (with just a ContactID field, deriving tables have FK), this would not be mapped in EF.

Is this setup doable ? 
Also, what will happen in the ObjectContext ? What kind of temporary key does EF generate before calling SaveChanges ? Will it be unique across objects ?

Thanks for any thoughts.
mike.

Answer (score 1):

We use a similiar construction with the folowing db design:

ContactEntity

- ID

ContactPossibility

- ID
- Position
- ContactTypeID
- ContactEntityID

Address

- ID (=PK and FK to ContactPossibility.ID)
- Street
- etc.

Telephone

- ID (=PK and FK to ContactPossibility.ID)
- Number
- etc.

Person

- ID (=PK and FK to ContactEntity.ID)
- FirstName
- etc.

Company

- ID (=PK and FK to ContactEntity.ID)
- Name
- etc.

This results in the entity model in two abstract classes: ContactEntity (CE) & ContactPossibility (CP) and multiple derived classes (Address=CP, Email=CP, Person=CE, Company=CE). The abstract and derived classes (rows in the db ;) share the same unique identifier, because we use an ID field in derived classes that's a foreign key to the primary key of the abstract class. And we use Guid's for this, because our software has the requirement to function properly off-line (not connected to the main database) and we have to deal smoothly with synchronisation issues. Also, what's the problem with Guid's?

Entity Framework does support this db / class design very good and we have a lot of pleasure from this design.

> Is this setup doable ? 
>   Also, what will happen in the ObjectContext ? 
>   What kind of temporary key does EF generate before calling SaveChanges ? 
>   Will it be unique across objects ?

The proposed setup is very very doable!
The ObjectContext acts fine and will insert, update and delete the right tables for derived classes without effort. Temporary keys? You don't need them if you use the pattern of an ID for derived classes that is both primary key and foreign key to the abstract class. And with Guid's you can be pretty sure that's unique across objetcs.

Furthermore: The foreignKey from CP to CE will provide every CE (Person, Company, User, etc.) with a trackable collection of ContactPossibilities. Which is real cool and handy.

Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly the kind of design I'm trying to achieve. I have a similar 'CP' table acting as a many-to-many table. One additional question (well a composite one actually..) : do you map the base classes (CP, CE) to their underlying table or not ? if you do, I suppose we are in a TPT setup (not TPC) or am I wrong ? If it is TPT, doesn't it produce nasty SQL with lots of unions ? thanks.

Comment: (update for my last question : I suppose that's where your 'ContactTypeID' in CP comes in as a discriminator in your base class ? so you don't have to union all your contactpossibility tables to find out the type, right ?)

Comment: Hi Mike, CP table acting as a many-to-many table... In my case this acts as a 1(CE) to many (CP). Yes, I map the (abstract) base classes to their underlying tables, actually the EntityModel generator does this for me ;) And yes, this is a Table-Per-Type scenario. This scenario gives some database optimisation as well because you have to keep track of less foreign keys and it's easier to maintain and expand with other CP or CE "Types".

Comment: Yeah, ContactTypeID is just a "lookup", with values of Private, Work, etc. And about the nasty SQL. I never looked at it in detail, I trust Microsoft for doing a good job there, and in my project easy-coding and RAD have preference above performance. It's not a high traffic system so I don't worry about that to much.

Comment: can be helpfull: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/b7589915-2e14-4c59-9c53-edc2e7d6f7c8/

Comment: thanks a lot Joep. I am a bit worried though about performance, have a look at this one : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/08/17/performance-considerations-when-using-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx My system is small right now, but I will have about 10 to 15 classes inheriting on the base abstract class...

Comment: Hmmm...a little alarming, I have to admit. We currently have 3 to 5 classes in inheritance structure. And, yes we made a rough redesign last week with this and I remember being a little surprised that loading / displaying data took a fraction linger, really! After all, you have to decide what's the trade off...BTW would you consider my answer as THE answer or what? ;) obsessed with gaining reputation...

Comment: OK, I've been running some tests.

Comment: Hi Mike, reviewing some of my answers, this one I really put a lot of effort in, could you accept it as THE answer? Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

(not enough space in the comments section)

I've been running some tests. 
The thing is you're OK as long as you ONLY specify the subtype you're querying for (ex. 'Address' in your case). 
But if you query for the base type (even if you don't need the subtypes info), ex. only ContactPossibility.ID, the generated SQL will UNION all subtype tables. 
So querying your 'trackable' collection of ContactPossibilities can create a performance problem.

I tried to work around this by unmapping the base entity and split the inherited entities to their own table + the common table, basically transforming the TPT into TPC : this worked fine from a conceptual perspective (after a lot of edmx editing). 
Until I realized this was stupid... :) Indeed in that case you will always need to Union all underlying tables to query for the common data...
(Though I'm not sure in the case described at the end of this post, didn't pursue to test it)

So I guess, since mostly I will need to query for a specific type (person, company, address, phone,..), it's gonna be OK for now and hoping MS will come with a fix in EF4.5.

So I'll have to be careful when querying, another interesting example :
Let's say you want to select a person and then query for his address, something like (tried to follow your naming) :
`var person = from b in context.ContactEntities.OfType-Person-()
                          where b.FirstName.StartsWith("X")
                          select b;`
`var address = from a in context.ContactPossibilities.OfType-Address-()
                         where **a.ContactEntity == person.FirstOrDefault()**
                         select a;`
this will produce a Union between all the tables of the Contact derived entities, and performance issues : generated SQL takes ContactPossibility table and joins to Address on ContactPossibilityID, **then joins a union of all Contact derived tables joined with the base Contact table**, before finally joining a filtered Person table.

However, consider the following alternative :
`var person = from b in context.ContactEntities.OfType-Person-()
                          where b.FirstName.StartsWith("X")<BR>
                          select b;`
`var address = from a in context.ContactPossibilities.OfType-Address-()
                         where **a.ContactID == person.FirstOrDefault().ID**
                         select a;`
This will work fine : generated SQL takes ContactPossibility table and joins to Address on ContactPossibilityID, and then joins the filtered Person table.

Mike.

Comment: note that the following alternative to the same queries also works fine : var address = from d in context.Contactpossibilities.OfType<Address>()
                         join e in context.Contacts.OfType<Person>() on d.ContactID equals e.ContactID
                         select d;